# According to the C standard, is a negative integer literal interpreted as single literal, or operator and literal?

Tags: c, parsing, compilation, numeric, literals

How are negative integers interpreted by the C standard/compilers - as a single literal, or as a (unary) operator and a numeric literal?

For example, is `-16` interpreted a `-16` or `-(16)`?

Comment: As a curiosity, there's a reason why C std libs usually define `INT_MIN` like `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` and that's because the positive number 2147483648 is too large to fit inside type `int` so it would become a `long` or such instead. Which is bad for various implicit type reasons like assigning from wider to narrower type. And adding the unary `-` operator to `2147483648` won't help because the integer constant would already have `long` type by then.

Comment: C uses _literal_ for other things.  C identifies 16 as an _integer constant_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C 2018 6.4.4.1 1 shows the grammar for integer constants. It says an *integer-constant* is one of:

- *decimal-constant* *integer-suffix*<sub>opt</sub>
- *octal-constant* *integer-suffix*<sub>opt</sub>
- *hexadecimal-constant* *integer-suffix*<sub>opt</sub>

Since we are only interested in how these start, the *integer-suffix* does not concern us. The following grammar rules show:

- A *decimal-constant* starts with a *nonzero-digit*, which is of course one of `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, or `9`.
- An *octal-constant* starts with `0`.
- A *hexadecimal-constant* starts with `0x` or `0X`.

Therefore, no *integer-constant* starts with `-` or `+`.

`-16` is parsed as the unary `-` operator followed by the integer constant `16`. This forms an integer constant expression as specified in C 2018 6.6 6, which says:

> … An *integer constant expression* shall have integer type and shall only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose results are integer constants, `_Alignof` expressions, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts…

Comment: May be worth noting that the negation of the `-` sign is the result of the unary minus operator described in 6.5.3.3

Answer (score 5):

`-16` is two tokens: an operator `-` and an *integer constant* with value 16 and type `int`.

---

Try below. Even library constants are carefully constructed to avoid `-2147483648` which has the same *value* as `(-0x7fffffff-1)` but is a wider *type* as `2147483648` is outside the `int` range.

```
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define TOSTRING(x) STRINGIFY(x)
puts(TOSTRING(INT_MIN));
```

Output

```
(-0x7fffffff-1)
```

Comment: `0x80000000` does not have a *wider* type: on a 32-bit architecture it's type is `unsigned`, which has the same width as `int`, but is a different type. The periphrases `(-0x7fffffff-1)` is necessary to compute `INT_MIN` with type `int`.

Comment: @chqrlie Oui, of course.  Answer amended.